# Apply border effect on text and PNG images in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am looking to apply the following effect on text widgets, and png images in Flutter.

original

[image]

desired border effect

[image]

The above effect was actually applied using [borderize.com](https://borderize.com/).

How can I do this on Flutter?

Comment: Maybe you can use shadow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303882/how-to-add-shadow-to-the-text-in-flutter

Comment: unfortunately, I don't think that would work. Shadow is of the same dimension as the original text. here, the case is quite different.

Comment: Otherwise you've to draw paint